# Extract text before last space in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I want to extract text before the last space from column A and add it to column B.

**Example of input:**

Chicago A12

New York GE8

United States of America AB8

**Wanted output:**

Chicago

New York

United States of America

```
ColumnB = 
VAR string_length = LEN('Data'[ColumnA])
RETURN
TRIM(
    LEFT(
        SUBSTITUTE('Data'[ColumnA];" "; REPT(" "; string_length));string_length)
)
```

This does only work if I have one word before the space.

**Output:**

Chicago

New

United

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have last 3 characters behind your Inpurt such as A12, GED or so on

Create New Field and add below expression to it.

Note: Assuming you are not having City column as Null or empty, else you will have to add one more condition of if

```
Expected Result = LEFT('Table'[City];LEN('Table'[City])-3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't always have 3 characters.

Comment: Ok then what exactly is your criteria?
There has to be known pattern which can be dealt with.

Comment: I have two known patterns, is it possible to create a condition using IF in Power BI?

Comment: yes it is, what exactly is your pattern and condition. let me know I will try to work it

Comment: I found another solution for cases having more than 1 space:

ColumnB = 
Var FirstSpace = FIND(" ";'Data'[ColumnA])
Return LEFT('Data'[ColumnA]; LEN('Data'[ColumnA]) - FirstSpace)

Is it possible to consolidate these two options using if?